# Removing multiple directories for multiple users using Powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach

I hope you good this fine Thursday afternoon. I wonder if you can help me.

I'm trying to write a `ForEach-Object` statement that will cycle through a list of usernames and remove some directories.

Imaging the scenario where a Remote Desktop Terminal Server has 50+ users and it's running out of space on the C: drive because everyone has a lot of files in `c:\users\%username%\appdata\local\temp`.  I would like to write a script that looks removes that directory for all users.

So my fingers have lead me to type the following (I have created a csv with the column heading SamAccountName and some usernames in the rows below, called users.csv and placed in the root of c:) - To add to this, the script will eventually contain multiple directories:

`Import-Csv -path c:\users.csv | ForEach-Object { Remove-Item -Path c:\users\$_.SamAccountName\Appdata\Local\Temp -Recurse -Force }`

The error message is:

`Cannot find path 'C:\users\@{SamAccountName=user1}.SamAccountName\Appdata\Local\Temp'`

User1 does exist but it appears powershell does not call the variable as I expect. Of course, I need the path to return `C:\users\user1\Appdata\Local\Temp`

Can you suggest the correct method here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path is a string.  To use an object property in a expandable string, use the `$()` sub-expression syntax.

```
Import-Csv -path c:\users.csv | ForEach-Object { Remove-Item -Path "c:\users\$($_.SamAccountName)\Appdata\Local\Temp" -Recurse -Force }
```

Comment: Yep, same suggestion as above. Confirmed solution. Thank you also

Answer (score 1):

hope you're having a good one too!

Your issue is being caused as you're trying to access a property of an object within a string, in order to do this you must encapsulate it like so:

```
$($_.SamAccountName)
```

The whole line would read:

```
Import-Csv -path c:\users.csv | ForEach-Object { Remove-Item -Path c:\users\$($_.SamAccountName)\Appdata\Local\Temp -Recurse -Force }
```

Give that a try and let me know if that works!

Comment: Bingo. Simple as that.  Thank you very much kind sir